# Getting Error on StandardScalar Fit_Transform

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd

 dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
 X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
 y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

Ok so here is the problem.
both X and y are single feature and have one column. As you can see X is a **matrix**. and y is a **vector**
     X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
     y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

Now when I run `y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)` I get the error that it is a 1D array. And if i change `y = dataset.iloc[:, 2:3].values` making it a 2D array. 
But I want it to stay as 1D array since its the dependent variable and want it to stay that way. Also i solved earlier different examples where I had to rescale similar data, and it did not give me this kind of error. Not sure why it is giving me now. Moreover i am watching a video while coding and in the video everything is the same but he doesn't get any error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

StandardScaler is meant to work on the features, not labels or target data. 
Hence only works on 2-d Data. Please see here for documentation:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling

What you can do is, use [scale function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.scale). StandardScaler is just a wrapper over this function.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
y = scale(y)
```

Or if you want to use StandarScaler, you need to reshape your `y` to a 2-d array like this:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

StandardScaler used to work with 1d arrays but with a DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1,1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1,-1) if it contains a single sample.

So, following the solution you are looking for:

```
sc_y = StandardScaler()
y = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
y = y.flatten()
```

Comment: No need to specify or author of the question, your answer is already for him.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)

sc_y = StandardScaler()
y = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
y = y.flatten()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `flatten` to get a 1D array from the 2D array:

```
y.flatten()
```